# YouTube iframe, browser looks for file locally

Tags: html, iframe

I have a problem where I am building some html pages on my local machine and I am trying to embed a youtube video into a page using the provided code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/oBjWLXLroWc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

However when I test the page locally I get file not found C:\desktop\testsite\http://www.youtube.com...., etc

Anyone know why this is happening, I don't believe I have encountered this before.

Browsers used are latest FF and latest Chrome, both show file not found. Have checked all code and nothing seems wrong, I can show local content (same directory) in the iframe no problem. Also tested with other external sites/resources and same issue.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe can't find YouTube videos in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032125/iframe-cant-find-youtube-videos-in-html)

Answer (score 6):

Add an http: to the start of your src:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oBjWLXLroWc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I think what @Marty is trying to achieve by using ...src="//www.youtube.... is to have the iframe automatically use the protocol/scheme specified in the address/location bar.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are accessing the file via `"file://C:/desktop/testsite/index.htm"` or something similar?

`"...src="//www.youtube."...` uses the protocol/scheme in the address/location bar which in this case is `"file://...."` which would give you the result you are experiencing.

To fix this you need to install some web server software WAMP or IIS  depending on if you wish to do server side coding at some point.

PHP - WAMP - http://www.wampserver.com/en/

ASP.NET IIS - http://www.iis.net/

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I already had the http protocol at the start of the youtube url in the iframe. I moved the file WAMP www, localhost/test.html and it still seems to be looking for it locally. I get The requested URL /http//www.youtube.com/embed/oBjWLXLroWc was not found on this server. Very strange possibly something with my PC? Thanks for everyo9nes response, I'll get this figured out.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you are developing locally. Try using WAMP or XAMP to develop. Or upload your changes to your domain and test again. As heems mentioned, you can adjust your code to use the absolute path by including the http:// to your url. Using just // takes you to the base or root of your path. Because the base of your html document is your C: drive, it goes to that to find/build the URL.

This page may help explain it better than I can. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme